# How to control number of messages to weblogic MQ queues

Tags: weblogic12c, mq

I have configured a JMS server, a JMS queue and a connection factory in WebLogic. My application listen to the MQ queues configured on this weblogic to consume those messages and transform and send it to down stream applications.
My issue is that the upstream application is pumping way too many messages to weblogic MQ queue  and my application is not able to consume those messages at the same rate.
this is piling up the message queues.

Is there a way to control the messages from upstream application to my application weblogic queues, so that my application can work on the existing messages before taking any new messages into the queue?

I am seeing so many settings in weblogic but I am not sure which one to be used

Weblogic 12.1.1 4
Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic supports data size and message count quotas. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wlach/pagehelp/JMSjmsserverjmsserverconfigthresholdstitle.html).

You could assign maximum queue depth and thus prevent sender to send to many messages at once.